# Como inicializar variáveis BSO e PSO do ambiente Primavera?

Tags: c#

Eu tenciono inicializar duas variáveis de contexto sendo `ErpBS BSO` e `StdBSInterfPub PSO` quando adiciono uma extensão ao Primavera.

**Porquê?**
Gostava de usar estas variáveis com classes estáticas e/ou com forms (que não são os da API do Primavera). Poderia definir o contexto ou ter um "contexto geral"?

Como posso fazer a deteção de quando é colocada uma extensão no Primavera?

De momento as únicas maneiras que sei para fazer isto é usar a função `DepoisDeAbrirEmpresa` ou atribuir o contexto através de classes que por si fazem uso do seu contexto especifico (Por exemplo `ClassName : FichaArtigos`).

```
using Primavera.Extensibility.BusinessEntities.ExtensibilityService.EventArgs;
using Primavera.Extensibility.Base.Editors;

namespace Projeto
{
    class ClassName : FichaArtigos
    {        
         public override void AntesDeEditar(string Artigo, ref bool Cancel, ExtensibilityEventArgs e)
         {
              base.AntesDeEditar(Artigo, ref Cancel, e);
              AMinhaClassStatic.PSO = PSO;
              AMinhaClassStatic.BSO = BSO;
         }
    }
}
```

Gostava de poder inicializar as variáveis assumindo que a empresa já se encontra aberta.

**EDITADO 19-12-2019**

Exemplo da `AMinhaClassStatic`, pedido nos comentários. Este exemplo mostra como não é possível usar as variáveis sem primeiro inicializar.

```
using ErpBS100;
using StdPlatBS100;

namespace Projeto
{
    class AMinhaClassStatic
    {
        public static ErpBS BSO;
        public static StdBSInterfPub PSO;

        public static void teste()
        {
             PSO.Dialogos.MostraAviso("teste");
             BSO.Base.Clientes.AlteraCodigoCliente("TSTE", "TESTE");
        }
    }
}
```

`public static ErpBS BSO = new ErpBS();`
Aparenta não ajudar.

`public static StdBSInterfPub PSO = new StdBSInterfPub();`
Leva argumentos do qual não sei quais são.

**tl;dr** Pretendo inicializar `BSO` que é uma variável de contexto primavera do tipo `ErpBS` e inicializar `PSO` que é uma variável referente à plataforma do tipo `StdBSInterfPub`, seria possível inicializar um com contexto e outro com o ambiente da plataforma?

Comment: Não faço ideia de como o Primavera influencia no problema, mas estranhei o fato de nem `AMinhaClassStatic`, `PSO` ou `BSO` estarem definidas no seu código. O que são esses objetos?

Comment: @Woss O problema é querer usar variáveis da API mas não poder usar as mesmas sem primeiro inicializar elas. Eu estou ciente que o que tenciono fazer não é a forma mais correta de fazer isto mas ter este conhecimento dava jeito. Vê o edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendo o objetivo de criar a classe de contexto, e assim poder usar ao longo do projecto, mas algumas notas importantes.

Todas as classes de extensibilidade que herdem das classes base PRIMAVERA vão ter essas duas propriedades disponíveis para usar correctamente inicializaras, logo o contexto deixa de ser necessário. Se o seu projeto tem várias classes e formulários que não herdem, aí o que recomendo a implementação do padrão [singleton](https://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns) para ter acesso a única instância dessas duas propriedades, que teriam de inicializavas no evento `depoisabrirempresa()`.

Comment: O método de declarar o PSO e BSO no DepoisDeAbrirEmpresa é um método que tenho feito mas isso requer que cada mudança na extensão na altura do seu desenvolvimento me faça reiniciar o Primavera para ele voltar a dar trigger à função. Possívelmente deveria repensar o código.

Comment: Para alguém com o mesmo problema que possa eventualmente ver isto usem #Diretivas de pré-processamento, talvez possa ajudar ao vosso desenvolvimento e resolver o problema. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if